# How to solve this error

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EF Code first in my project.On creating a many to many relationship between my two entities i am getting following exception:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ServiceEmployee_dbo.Employee_EmployeeId' on table 'ServiceEmployee' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Here is my database edmx file:
[image]

I am getting the above mentioned error when i am creating a many to many relationship between **Employee** and **Services**.

Can anybody please explain me the reason of this error and the solution as well??

Thanks!

**Edit**

Below is the fluent api i write to  create many to many relationship between **Employee** and **Services**.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
               .HasMany(e => e.Employees)
               .WithMany(e => e.Services)
               .Map(m =>
{
    m.MapLeftKey("ServiceId");
    m.MapRightKey("EmployeeId");
    m.ToTable("ServiceEmployee");
});
```

Comment: Incidentally I believe it to be bad database practice to implement many to many relationships. A better design would be to have an EmployeeService table that has a record for each Employee -> Service link. Thats my opinion anyway

Comment: @StevenWood thanks for your opinion but can you please explain me why to implement many to many relationship is a bad practice in your opinion ?

Comment: It is usually Inefficient and and difficult to maintain. for example, imagine that you have a cascade delete relationship both ways. deleting a record in one table will delete related records in the second table, but also all records in the first related to those in the second that were deleted, then it keeps going back and forth. This is very difficult to model before a query is run. Whilst I consider that it is usually bad practice, if done well and with proper regard for data redundancy they can and are used. It is mainly about how far into the theoretically perfect database you want.